# TextArea Getting Buried in iOS

Tags: css, ios

I've made a 'thelounge' theme and it uses '@mixin bottomSafeAreaFixBrowser' and it works as expected; the #form on the bottom isn't buried by the rest of the page, but if you click the forum/textarea and then click 'done' on iOS, some of the text is buried beneath the textarea.
[screenshot of buried beneath textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rripG.jpg)

Source: https://github.com/ianonapp/thelounge-theme-ianon

```
@mixin bottomSafeAreaFixBrowser {
  html, body, #viewport, #chat-container {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  #chat-container .messages:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 70px;
  }
  #form:focus-within {
    margin-bottom: 60px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (display-mode: standalone) {
  @include bottomSafeAreaFix()
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (display-mode: browser) {
  @include bottomSafeAreaFixBrowser()
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 390px) and (max-device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (display-mode: standalone) {
  @include bottomSafeAreaFix()
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 390px) and (max-device-height: 844px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (display-mode: browser) {
  @include bottomSafeAreaFixBrowser()
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-height : 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (display-mode: standalone) {
  @include bottomSafeAreaFix()
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-height : 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (display-mode: browser) {
  @include bottomSafeAreaFixBrowser()
}
    
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-height : 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) and (display-mode: standalone) {
  @include bottomSafeAreaFix()
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-height : 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) and (display-mode: browser) {
  @include bottomSafeAreaFixBrowser()
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 428px) and (max-device-height : 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) and (display-mode: standalone) {
  @include bottomSafeAreaFix()
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 428px) and (max-device-height : 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 3) and (display-mode: browser) {
  @include bottomSafeAreaFixBrowser()
}
```

I've made a 'thelounge' theme and it uses '@mixin bottomSafeAreaFixBrowser' and it works as expected; the #form on the bottom isn't buried by the rest of the page, but if you click the forum/textarea and then click 'done' on iOS, some of the text is buried beneath the textarea.

Comment: Please don't fill out text by repeating it - use the space to describe what debugging you have attempted and the results of that. Also, please include just enough code in your question so that we can reproduce the problem. External sites may disappear or get corrected which would render your question useless for future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example